# query ASE DB lock and the duration the lock is held

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am looking for a sql that prints out all DB locks currently are held and also the duration the locks have been held for ASE.
I would like to run that sql periodically so that we can monitor the DB health for lock issues.

Answer (score 1):

See the [master..monLocks](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1600/doc/html/san1393052505869.html) table for a list of granted locks and pending (blocked) lock requests.

The `WaitTime` column will give you the number of seconds a process has been waiting for a requested lock.  You should be able to use the rest of the columns in that table to build the desired query (NOTE: you may need to join with other tables ... depends on what info you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

There's also the system stored proc sp_object_stats.  From the [docs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/29a04b8081884fb5b715fe4aa1ab4ad2/16.0.3.4/en-US/ab756da6bc2b1014ab41d4dc52b0bf33.html?q=sp_object_stats):

"Shows lock contention, lock wait-time, and deadlock statistics for tables and indexes"

The output for a single object looks like:

```
    Object Name: pubtune..titles (dbid=7, objid=208003772,lockscheme=Datapages)

  Page Locks     SH_PAGE                UP_PAGE               EX_PAGE$
  ----------    ----------             ----------            ----------
  Grants:         94488                  4052                  4828
  Waits:               532                    500                   776
  Deadlocks:             4                      0                    24
  Wait-time:      20603764 ms           14265708 ms           2831556 ms
  Contention:         0.56%                 10.98%                13.79%

 *** Consider altering pubtune..titles to Datarows locking.
```

Displays the top 10 objects by default.